# Count parameter inconsistant, MPI_Bsend /MPI_Recieve

Tags: c, mpi

In the example found [here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Bsend.html), why is the count inconsistant in the second message

```
if (rank == src) {
    /* These message sizes are chosen to expose any alignment problems */
    MPI_Bsend( msg1, 7, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, comm );
    MPI_Bsend( msg2, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag, comm );
    MPI_Bsend( msg3, 17, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, comm );
}

if (rank == dest) {
    MPI_Recv( rmsg1, 7, MPI_CHAR, src, tag, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
    MPI_Recv( rmsg2, 10, MPI_DOUBLE, src, tag, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
    MPI_Recv( rmsg3, 17, MPI_CHAR, src, tag, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
    if (strcmp( rmsg1, msg1 ) != 0) {
        errs++;
        fprintf( stderr, "message 1 (%s) should be %s\n", rmsg1, msg1 );fflush(stderr);
    }
```

Why is the count for the send and receive two inconsistant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` argument of `Recv` is only an upper bound on the amount of data to receive. This is convenient if we don't know the size of the payload at compile time. After the second `Recv` completes, `rmsg2` will contain the two doubles, and then some uninitialized data.

Comment: I do not doubt that your answer is correct and I realize discussion is generally frowned upon on Stack-overflow but why would the example in the link include something this?